# Calculate degree of a subgraph using r igraph

Tags: r, igraph, degrees

I know the degree of my global graph, but now I need to find the degrees of nodes within a subgraph. So, John has 4 friends in his school, but three friends in his class. How do I instruct igraph to count those three friends in his class, but not the rest in his school?

**My global graph**

```
library(igraph)
school <- read.table(text="
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
A   0   1   0   1   0   1   1
B   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
C   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
D   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
E   0   0   0   1   0   1   1
F   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
G   1   0   1   0   1   1   0", header=TRUE)

mat <- as.matrix(school)
g <- graph.adjacency(mat, mode="undirected", add.rownames = T)
```

**My affiliation matrix for classes P, Q, and R**

```
x <- read.table(text="
                    P   Q   R
                A   1   1   0
                B   0   0   1
                C   0   0   0
                D   1   0   1
                E   1   1   0
                F   0   1   0
                G   1   1   1", header=TRUE)

inc <- as.matrix(x)
ginc <- graph.incidence(inc)
```

**My subgraph for class P**

```
class_nodes <- names(which(inc[,"P"] == 1))
class_adj   <- mat[class_nodes, class_nodes]
class_graph <- graph.adjacency(class_adj, mode = "undirected")
```

I need to calculate the degree of nodes in subgraph "class_graph", but counting only their ties within the subgraph, not the global graph.

Comment: So with this sample data, what is the desired output so we can test possible solutions?

Comment: The desired output is the degree of nodes in subgraph "class_graph", but counting only their ties within the subgraph, not the global graph. I updated the question to make this clear.

Comment: The actual numeric values you expect given your definition would be even more clear.

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question. "A" has four friends in the global graph, but only three of them are affiliated to class "P". So I expect the degree of "A" to be three instead of four.  D's degree would be two in the subgraph as opposed to three in the global graph. Does this clarify the question?

Comment: Wait, A has four friends (B, D, F,G) but only two of those are in P (D, G). So wouldn't A's degree be 2? Or are you counting each node as being connected to itself?

Comment: You are totally right, my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all the nodes in class P with (we specifically extract the names so we can look them up in a different graph object).

```
V(ginc)[.nei("P")]$name
```

Then you can extract just that subset of connections from the main graph with

```
subg <- induced.subgraph(g, V(ginc)[.nei("P")]$name)
```

and you can calculate the degree of those nodes with

```
degree(subg)
# A D E G 
# 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: The function .nei gives me an error. Do you know why this may be?

Comment: What version of igraph are you using? This was tested with `igraph_1.1.2`. I think it was called something else in previous versions.

Comment: I have igraph 1.0.1

The error message is:

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function ".nei"

Comment: That's your Rstudio version which has nothing really to do with with igraph package version number. Check `sessionInfo()`. Maybe run `update.packages("igraph")`. Or look through the documentation of your installed version to see what the syntax was for extracting adjacent vertices.

Comment: You're right. My igraph is 1.0.1. Do you know what was the equivalent of .nei in this version?

Comment: Maybe it was `nei()` without the dot? No way for me to test on an old version.

Comment: I updated my igraph version and your code worked just fine -- thanks a lot!